# Why I Don't See Contents Of Folder When Tabbing?

Tags: windows-explorer

Usually if I remember correctly, when I browsed between multiple folders and was pointing mouse cursor on folder, I could see its contents, but not anymore:

[image]

All I see are icons; one with earth symbol and another with just a folder symbol. Do I need to re-enable sepcific option that I may have disabled earlier?